# Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'my-project'

Tags: jenkins, gradle, kotlin

I have a kotlin application and using the following gradle command to build it:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

This fine locally but has recently started breaking on Jenkins with the following error (it used to work)

```
Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'my-project'.
```

Why does it ask for `assembleDebug` on Jenkins? How can I fix it so that this error is not shown? I don't think I need `assembleDebug`.

Note: this is not an andriod project.

Answer (score 0):

`ANDROID_HOME` was the answer for me. Specifically, Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Environment variables -> Name: `ANDROID_HOME`, Value: Your Android SDK directory